# MySQLI - INSERT or UPDATE on duplicate, multiple users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Currently I update my table with the following query.

```
$query = "UPDATE `my_table` SET `views` = `views` + 1 
          WHERE `user_id` IN (".$users.")";
```

This updates all the users within the table to +1 on their respective views column value.

I need to insert a new row if this is a new day. To do this I found (via stack overflow) the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` function. This is working perfectly but i am not entirely sure on how to do this for multiple users within a single query (like my query above).

The current query I have so far is the following, but is limited to a single user

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `my_table` (`user_id`, `day`, `listing`) 
          VALUES (12, 2, 1)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views`=`views`+1";
```

I do not wish to put this query within a php foreach loop as it would perform slowly given the number of rows (40 - 100)

Comment: You need a combined key on user_id and day. Then you can use ON DUPLICATE

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple queries using mysql transactions: http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

```
function ExecuteTransaction($sqlStmts,$params){
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $n = count($sqlStmts);
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($rawStmts[$i]);
        $stmt->execute($params[$i]);
    }
    $conn->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    $conn->rollBack();
    return FALSE;
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    $conn->rollBack();
    return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;}
```

Here each entry in $sqlStmts i.e., $sqlStmts[$i] is a prepared statement and each $params i.e., $params[$i] is an array of parameters for the prepared statement $sqlStmts[$i]

But if you just want to execute them at a time, you should do something like

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `my_table` (`user_id`, `day`, `listing`)
          VALUES (12,2,1),(13,3,2),(14,4,3)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views`=`views`+1";
```